# Remove notifications icon or make notifications fade after a while

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, unity

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10, along with Gnome 3 to replace Unity. I'm using the classic Gnome look rather than the new one which is way too much like Unity for my tastes. Seems like everything is getting harder and harder to configure, fewer and fewer options. It's driving me nuts.

Anyway, on occasion I get various notifications, which appear both as a brief bubble (sometimes, if I'm lucky) and in the panel as an annoying "mail" like icon. The bubbles are fine, and the icon too if not for the fact that unlike the bubbles the icon stays and gives me a growing list of old news that I have to clear manually.

Can I remove the icon, or make it automatically clear notifications after, say, 30 seconds?

Also, I can't seem to make Banshee show up in the sound menu as it advertises. I can change the settings to get an additional Banshee icon in the panel but not only shouldn't that be necessary when I already have a sound menu (or a volume control at least) it's also an ugly icon that kinda grates on my eyes.